# bootstrap4 media query mixin not working

Tags: sass, media-queries, bootstrap-4

I'm having an issue using the mixin for media query breakpoints.  I have included variables.scss, and _breakpoints.scss, but whenever I try to call a query it gives me an error:

```
        li.product{
        width:100%;

        @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
            width:48%;
        }
        @include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
            width:22.05%;
        }
    }
```

and it spouts this error when I try to compile:

```
formatted: Error: Invalid CSS after "...a-breakpoint-up": expected "{", was "(lg) {"
```

How am I supposed to write the query?

Answer (score 1):

I had a typo, stating @media, instead of @include.  It now works.